# Force compiler to emit error on move constructor not defined with a base class deleted copy ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, deleted-functions

Consider a base class which prevents copy construction and copy assignment like this:

```
class NonCopyable {
    public:
        NonCopyable() = default;
        ~NonCopyable() = default;

        NonCopyable(NonCopyable const&)                 = delete;
        NonCopyable& operator=(NonCopyable const&)      = delete;
};
```

Our developers can now include this class, and use it to disable copy for inherited classes, like this:

```
class CopyTest : public NonCopyable {
    public:
        CopyTest() {
            std::cout << "copy test created" << std::endl;
        }

        ~CopyTest() {
            std::cout << "copy test deleted" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

When I try to use the `CopyTest` class:

```
CopyTest ct, ct1(ct);
```

or

```
CopyTest ct;
CopyTest ct1 = ct2;
```

The compiler emit an error : `use of deleted function xxx` (where xxx is my deleted copy ctor, or copy operator)

Then, if I want to `std::move` a `CopyTest` object :

```
CopyTest ct;
CopyTest ct1 = std::move(ct);
```

The compiler emit the same error (use of deleted function xxx - where xxx remains my copy ctor or assignment operator).

If I remind correctly, it's because the developer has not defined the proper move ctor/assignment operator.

**Is it possible to force the compiler to tell the developer of the `CopyTest` class that the move error is here because he has not defined the proper move ctor/assignment operator, and not because the copy ctor/assignment operator is deleted on the base class?**

Platform:
Debian 9
GCC 6.3.0

Compilation flags: `-fpermissive -ggdb -std=c++11`

Comment: Any good developer will know that the probable cause of this error is the lack of a move constructor (He **is** using `std::move`, after all). I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't want to rely on other people nor my probable skills, and thought that an exact compiler error was easier to be understood by beginners like me...

Comment: The compiler error is *exact*: the implicitly defined move constructor is deleted, because the copy ctor is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&)                 = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(NonCopyable &&)      = delete;
```

that now complains about the base class move ctor being deleted.

Comment: The goal here is to know if the compiler can complains about the child class move ctor not present, not about the base class move ctor deleted?

Comment: @Ayak973 The child class gets a move ctor written for it that fails *because* the base class has a deleted move ctor.  The compiler is saying why the derived class's move ctor cannot be written for you.

Comment: My reasoning was biased, I understand better now with your comment

Answer (score 0):

Formally speaking, the implicitly generated move ctor/assignment is defined as "deleted" in the base class `NonCopyable` itself. A "deleted" move ctor/assignment is just ignored by overload resolution (instead of being deleted in the strict sense). Since `NonCopyable` is not copyable and not movable, any subclass will have it's implicit (and =default) copy and move operations be defined as deleted.

Under strict iso c++, your design has the wanted semantics but unfortunately, most compilers do not strictly enforce the so called *rule of five*, but only enforce a subset of the *implicitly deleted* rule. For example, having user declared destructor for a class implies that the implicit (and =default) definitions of all copy and move operation will be deleted, but I don't know of a compiler that fails to compile or emit a warning when the implicitly declared copy constructor would be ODR used for such a class.

I came across this bug report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58407#c16 . It suggest that compilers will probably begin to enforce or warn against the *rule of five* violations.

Comment: The "Rule of Five" is not a rule of the language though.

Comment: @Deduplicator I know, it's more of a guideline, but I used it as a shortcut.